# Glyphicons blink on refresh in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap glyphicons. They are working nicely, but with Chrome browser, the glyphicons blink when the page loads

For example:

1. Open this link on Bootstrap:

   - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs
2. Once loaded, Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or refresh.
3. You will see the glyphicons blink.

How can I fix it so they don't blink?

**Here's a screenshot**:

[image: Example]

**Note:** This only happens in Chrome, not FF or IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, this is a problem with having a [*flash of unstyled content* (**FOUC**)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Specifically, this is what Paul Irish calls a [*flash of unstyled **text*** (**FOUT**)](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/):

> In **Firefox**, basically the text is in a default webfont until the custom font is ready
>
> [image: FF]
>
> **Webkit** takes a very [different approach](http://webkit.org/blog/66/the-fouc-problem/), and very intentionally. They believe it’s better to keep the text invisible until the font is ready. This way, there is no moment where the text flashes into its newly upgraded self
>
> [image: Webkit]

In other words, this issue isn't so easily overcome.

You can attempt to *minimize* the impact by:

- Using **gzip** to shrink the file so it downloads quicker
- Using **caching** so the client can use an existing copy rather than grabbing a new one.

The heavy handed approach would be to wait to display the page to the user until everything was rendered, but I would strongly recommend against this.  User are very impatient for initial load times but are considerably more forgiving when it comes to rendering additional content.

Comment: Great answer and awesome edit btw! gzip is being used already. As I understand, it's just an webkit thing. My biggest issue was that because the glyphicons loaded at a later stage, my other text / layout was changing because first the glyphicon is just 1px and when it's loaded, it's e.g. 15 px. I fixed that by giving the glyphicons a fixed size.

Answer (score 3):

The glyphicons blink/flicker on page reloads, but the bigger problem for me (I'm using Bootstrap 3) is that **the page flickers as elements resize around the glyphicons**.  Adding this to my CSS stopped the resizing for me:

```
.glyphicon {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Thanks to my source: https://www.garysieling.com/blog/preventing-icon-flicker-using-glyphicons

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem but solved it by adding `.woff` and `.woff2` as new MIME-types `font/x-woff` in IIS.

This stopped the glyph-icons from blinking immediately as Chrome now caches the font-file correctly.

To see if this may apply to you, open the debug-console in Chrome (F12) on the site it blinks and you will find an error related to the glyph-font-files where the browser interprets them as the wrong MIME type.